# Accessing a closed file with the help of Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently building automation of a vs code extension and the extension basically works on hover action (`registerHoverProvider` method). Since this method only works when the file that you are hovering on is open inside the editor, I cannot make use of it. For me, the use case is to work on a file that is currently not open inside the editor and pass it along. Any suggestions on how I can do that?

Current code:

```
vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider([{ scheme: 'file', language: 'typescript' }, { scheme: 'file', language: 'javascript' }], {
        provideHover: async (document, position) => {

// Some code here

}
```

On the above code, I want to change this in such a way that the function works on the `document` and `position` parameters without the `registerHoverProvider` method. I can give the file path as an input and that should be the document/file to be read.

Comment: use `vscode.workspace.fs` to read and write files, how do you get the doc and pos without the `registerHoverProvider`

Comment: does fs.readFile() function give me the capability to index each word by position? (line and word index)

Comment: no, if you need document functionality open the file, do your stuff and close the file.

Answer (score 0):

By default, VSCode opens files in preview mode. This is indicated by their name being italic in the menu bar. As John noted, you can double click on the file to fully open it.

To disable this behavior, try setting:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

also Ctrl+P -- For targetting a file Alt+Enter -- For Opening that file into next tab

Comment: I may have been a bit unclear, but the usecase is to automate the extension without opening VSCode itself. Basically, the javascript/typescript that I would write would act on the file, and not the editor.